# Invert interpolation to give the variable associated with a desired interpolation function value

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to invert an interpolated function using scipy's interpolate function. Let's say I create an interpolated function,

```
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate
interpolatedfunction = interpolated.interp1d(xvariable,data,kind='cubic')
```

Is there some function that can find x when I specify a:

```
interpolatedfunction(x) == a
```

In other words, "I want my interpolated function to equal a; what is the value of xvariable such that my function is equal to a?"

I appreciate I can do this with some numerical scheme, but is there a more straightforward method? What if the interpolated function is multivalued in xvariable?

Comment: so you want `x` where `interpolatedfunction(x) == a`?

Comment: That is correct. Is there a built-in function that does such a thing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After creating an interpolated function `interp_fn`, you can find the value of `x` where `interp_fn(x) == a` by the roots of the function

```
interp_fn2 = lambda x: interp_fn(x) - a
```

There are number of options to find the roots in `scipy.optimize`.  For instance, to use Newton's method with the initial value starting at 10:

```
from scipy import optimize

optimize.newton(interp_fn2, 10)
```

---

#### Actual example

Create an interpolated function and then find the roots where `fn(x) == 5`

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate, optimize

x = np.arange(10)
y = 1 + 6*np.arange(10) - np.arange(10)**2
y2 = 5*np.ones_like(x)
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y2,'k-')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot of f(x) and y=5]

```
# create the interpolated function, and then the offset
# function used to find the roots

interp_fn = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, 'quadratic')
interp_fn2 = lambda x: interp_fn(x)-5

# to find the roots, we need to supply a starting value
# because there are more than 1 root in our range, we need 
# to supply multiple starting values.  They should be 
# fairly close to the actual root

root1, root2 = optimize.newton(interp_fn2, 1), optimize.newton(interp_fn2, 5)

root1, root2
# returns:
(0.76393202250021064, 5.2360679774997898)
```

Comment: Very nice solution!

Answer (score 18):

There are dedicated methods for finding roots of cubic splines. The simplest to use is the `.roots()` method of [InterpolatedUnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline) object:

```
spl = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)
roots = spl.roots()
```

This finds all of the roots instead of just one, as generic solvers (`fsolve`, `brentq`, `newton`, `bisect`, etc) do.

```
x = np.arange(20)
y = np.cos(np.arange(20))
spl = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)
print(spl.roots())
```

outputs `array([  1.56669456,   4.71145244,   7.85321627,  10.99554642, 14.13792756,  17.28271674])`

However, you want to equate the spline to some arbitrary number a, rather than 0. One option is to rebuild the spline (you can't just subtract `a` from it):

```
solutions = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y - a).roots()
```

Note that none of this will work with the function returned by `interp1d`; it does not have `roots` method. For that function, using generic methods like `fsolve` is an option, but you will only get one root at a time from it. In any case, why use `interp1d` for cubic splines when there are more powerful ways to do the same kind of interpolation?

#### Non-object-oriented way

Instead of rebuilding the spline after subtracting `a` from data, one can  directly subtract `a` from spline coefficients. This requires us to drop down to non-object-oriented interpolation methods. Specifically, [`sproot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.sproot.html#scipy.interpolate.sproot) takes in a tck tuple prepared by [`splrep`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html#scipy.interpolate.splrep), as follows:

```
tck = splrep(x, y, k=3, s=0)
tck_mod = (tck[0], tck[1] - a, tck[2])
solutions = sproot(tck_mod)
```

I'm not sure if messing with `tck` is worth the gain here, as it's possible that the bulk of computation time will be in root-finding anyway. But it's good to have alternatives.

Comment: Excellent alternative as .roots() finds all of the roots (if they exist).

Answer (score 9):

If your data are monotonic you might also try the following:

```
inversefunction = interpolated.interp1d(data, xvariable, kind='cubic')
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Especially useful for sampling from custom distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Mentioning another option because I found this page in a google search and the other option works for my simple use case. Hopefully it'll be of use to someone.

**If** the function you're interpolating is very simple and always has a 1:1 relationship between y and x, then you can simply take your data, swap x and y when you pass it into `interp1d`, and then call the interpolation function in that direction.

Adapting code from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.exp(-x/3.0)
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
xnew = np.arange(0, 9, 0.1)
ynew = f(xnew)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, ynew, '-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

When x and y have been swapped you can call `swappedInterpolationFunction(a)` to get the x value where that would occur.

```
f = interpolate.interp1d(y, x)
xnew = np.arange(np.exp(-9/3), np.exp(0), 0.01)
ynew = f(xnew)
plt.plot(y, x, 'o', xnew, ynew, '-')
plt.title("Inverted")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Of course, if the function ever has multiple x values for a given y value (like sine or a parabola) then this will not work because it will no longer be a 1:1 function from x to y, and the above answers are necessary. This is just a simplification in a limited use case.