# Using scipy gaussian kernel density estimation to calculate CDF inverse

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing

The `gaussian_kde` function in `scipy.stats` has a function `evaluate` that can returns the value of the PDF of an input point. I'm trying to use `gaussian_kde` to estimate the inverse CDF. The motivation is for generating Monte Carlo realizations of some input data whose statistical distribution is numerically estimated using KDE. Is there a method bound to `gaussian_kde` that serves this purpose?

The example below shows how this should work for the case of a Gaussian distribution. First I show how to do the PDF calculation to set up the specific API I'm trying to achieve:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.stats import norm, gaussian_kde

npts_kde = int(5e3)
n = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=npts_kde)
kde = gaussian_kde(n)

npts_sample = int(1e3)
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, npts_sample)
kde_pdf = kde.evaluate(x)
norm_pdf = norm.pdf(x)
```

[image: Demo of KDE approximation of the PDF of a normal distribution]

Is there an analogously simple way to compute the inverse CDF? The `norm` function has a very handy `isf` function that does exactly this:

```
cdf_value = np.sort(np.random.rand(npts_sample))
cdf_inv = norm.isf(1 - cdf_value)
```

[image: Demo of desired KDE approximation of the CDF of a normal distribution]

Does such a function exist for `kde_gaussian`? Or is it straightforward to construct such a function from the already implemented methods?

Comment: If your ultimate goal is resampling why not use the `resample` method?

Comment: My ultimate goal is not *random* resampling, but *correlated* resampling. If the `resample` method permitted me to pass in CDF values (the way that the `isf` method does), then my problem would be solved. But `resample` presumes I want to use a random uniform to generate the sample via the inverse CDF, which I do not.

Comment: How about a root finder, then? Would that be too slow?

Comment: Hmm, not sure I understand. I guess you're suggesting I run a root-finder for a numerical integration of the PDF?

Comment: I've never used this `kde` stuff, but the `integrate_box_1d` method sounds like almost the cdf to me, Maybe you can even put `-inf` for a boundary? And the cdf you can invert using a root finder  - not the fastest, obviously.

Comment: Yes, this is a really good suggestion. My numerical integration of the PDF using scipy.integrate.quad is about 50x slower than `integrate_box_1d`. So this will actually be quite fast.
If you write this up as a suggested answer, that will very likely be the accepted answer. Otherwise I'll write it up after making the explanation explicit and clear. Either way, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Looks like I got scooped. Anyway, glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method [`integrate_box_1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.integrate_box_1d.html) can be used to compute the CDF, but it is not vectorized; you'll need to loop over points. If memory is not an issue, rewriting its [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/stats/kde.py#L283) (which is essentially just a call to [`special.ndtr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ndtr.html)) in vector form may speed things up.

```
from scipy.special import ndtr
stdev = np.sqrt(kde.covariance)[0, 0]
pde_cdf = ndtr(np.subtract.outer(x, n)).mean(axis=1)
plot(x, pde_cdf)
```

The plot of the inverse function would be `plot(pde_cdf, x)`. If the goal is to compute the inverse function at a specific point, consider using [the inverse of interpolating spline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47276938), interpolating the computed values of the CDF.

Comment: I found I had to modify the pde_cdf line slightly: `pde_cdf = ndtr(np.subtract.outer(x, n)/stdev).mean(axis=1)`. You'll see the division by the standard deviation in the source code you point to. Mathematically, I think this is required anyway. And if you are lucky enough to look at things like a normal distribution, this sort-of does ok. But without the `stdev` it really breaks if you are looking at anything not "normal". It is working here because the width of your gaussian is 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

The question has been answered in the other answers but it took me a while to wrap my mind around everything. Here is a complete example of the final solution:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.special import ndtr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm, gaussian_kde

# create kde
npts_kde = int(5e3)
n = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=npts_kde)
kde = gaussian_kde(n)

# grid for plotting
npts_sample = int(1e3)
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, npts_sample)

# evaluate pdfs
kde_pdf = kde.evaluate(x)
norm_pdf = norm.pdf(x)

# cdf and inv cdf are available directly from scipy
norm_cdf = norm.cdf(x)
norm_inv = norm.ppf(x)

# estimate cdf
cdf = tuple(ndtr(np.ravel(item - kde.dataset) / kde.factor).mean()
            for item in x)

# estimate inv cdf
inversefunction = interpolate.interp1d(cdf, x, kind='cubic', bounds_error=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(6, 3))
ax[0].plot(x, norm_pdf, c='k')
ax[0].plot(x, kde_pdf, c='r', ls='--')
ax[0].set_title('PDF')
ax[1].plot(x, norm_cdf, c='k')
ax[1].plot(x, cdf, c='r', ls='--')
ax[1].set_title('CDF')
ax[2].plot(x, norm_inv, c='k')
ax[2].plot(x, inversefunction(x), c='r', ls='--')
ax[2].set_title("Inverse CDF")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use some python tricks for fast and memory-effective estimation of the CDF (based on [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/296317)):

```python
    from scipy.special import ndtr
    cdf = tuple(ndtr(np.ravel(item - kde.dataset) / kde.factor).mean()
                for item in x)
```

It works as fast as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47419857/14350255), but has linear (`len(kde.dataset)`) space complexity instead of the quadratic (actually, `len(kde.dataset) * len(x)`) one.

All you have to do next is to use inverse approximation, for instance, from [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution.monotone_fn_inverter.html).