# cummulative distribution function from probability distibution function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to estimate the cumulative distribution function from a  probability distribution function

for this I am using the lambda function (code given below), but it gives some negative values at the end of series

```py
Dj_lin = lambda x: 1 - sp.integrate.quad(mypdf_lin, 0, x)[0]
```

here mypdf_lin is my pdf function

is there any other way to estimate the cdf from pdf ?

Comment: if it should return 0 at this point you could do ```np.clip```

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417986/using-scipy-gaussian-kernel-density-estimation-to-calculate-cdf-inverse) might be able to help you?