# Is there a Python function to make a kernel density estimation (KDE) over a CDF?

Tags: python, kernel-density, scipy.stats

I have a simple CDF (cumulative distribution function) that I want to estimate using a KDE (kernel density estimation) in order to smooth out the 'steppy' nature of the CDF. The dataset is quite small (40 datapoints), so the steps are quite obvious in the CDF.

I saw that there are functions that do this in R (kCDF) and MatLab (ksdensity, with the option 'cdf'), but I need it in Python.

I tried to estimate the PDF first using scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde, and then get the CDF from the PDF, but this introduces a lot of unnecessary error. Ideally, I would like to use a KDE estimator directly over the CDF, would it be possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using scipy gaussian kernel density estimation to calculate CDF inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417986/using-scipy-gaussian-kernel-density-estimation-to-calculate-cdf-inverse)

Comment: This has nothing to do with R, or matlab and shouldn't be tagged as such. Also it is off-topic as "looking for recommendation or software".

Comment: Did you try with `statsmodels`? https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/kernel_density.html#The-KDE-is-a-distribution

Comment: I'm also looking for the same solution!

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to estimate the PDF first using scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde, and then get the CDF from the PDF, but this introduces a lot of unnecessary error. Ideally, I would like to use a KDE estimator directly over the CDF, would it be possible?

I don't think there is a distinction between normal KDE and "using a KDE estimator directly over the CDF". A kernel density estime PDF is the sum of a bunch of normal distribution PDFs, each with its mean at an observation and with scale determined by the bandwidth. A kernel density estimate CDF the integral of this PDF. The fact that R has a separate function `kCDF` and Matlab's `ksdensity` has a `cdf` option does not suggest to me that they are employing different algorithms tailored to estimating a CDF; these are just the interfaces of those languages by which one might expect to get a function that estimates a CDF from data.

> I tried to estimate the PDF first using `scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde`, and then get the CDF from the PDF, but this introduces a lot of unnecessary error

This depends on the method you used to "get the CDF from the PDF". Numerical quadruture using `scipy.integrate.quad` would be very inefficient, but I doubt it would introduce much error. Fitting a spline to the PDF and using the integral of the spline could also get you a nice CDF. But the most natural and accurate way is probably to use [`gaussian_kde.integrate_box_1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.integrate_box_1d.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.integrate_box_1d).

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
rng = np.random.default_rng(8218584346)

# sample from a distribution
dist = stats.cosine()
sample = dist.rvs(size=40, random_state=rng)

# compute the true CDF on a grid
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 300)
ref = dist.cdf(x)

# estimate the CDF using ECDF
ecdf = stats.ecdf(sample)
res_ecdf = ecdf.cdf.evaluate(x)

# estimate the CDF using `gaussian_kde.integrate_box_1d`
kde = stats.gaussian_kde(sample)
kde_cdf = np.vectorize(kde.integrate_box_1d)
res_kde = kde_cdf(-np.pi, x)

# compare the results
plt.plot(x, ref, label='reference CDF')
plt.plot(x, res_ecdf, label='empirical CDF')
plt.plot(x, res_kde, label='KDE CDF')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('CDF')
plt.legend()
```