# Pulling x-values of spline integer y-values?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have the given sample data and interpolated spline:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

x = [0.1, 1.5, 2.3, 5.5, 6.7, 7]
y = [5, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3]
s = interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=0)

xs = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 10000) #values for x axis
ys = s(xs)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xs, ys, label='spline')
plt.plot(x, y, 'x', label='collected data')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

I would like to pull the x values that correspond to the integer y values of the spline, but am not sure how to do this. I assume I will be using np.where() and have tried (to no avail):

```
root_index = np.where(ys == ys.round())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invert interpolation to give the variable associated with a desired interpolation function value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275957/invert-interpolation-to-give-the-variable-associated-with-a-desired-interpolatio)

Comment: Rather than generating the dense grid in the accepted answer, I would recommend the more analytical solution of calling `solve` on a `CubicSpline` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `find_roots` function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909373/how-to-find-the-exact-intersection-of-a-curve-as-np-array-with-y-0) to find the exact interpolated x-values:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

def find_roots(x, y):
    s = np.abs(np.diff(np.sign(y))).astype(bool)
    return x[:-1][s] + np.diff(x)[s] / (np.abs(y[1:][s] / y[:-1][s]) + 1)

x = [0.1, 1.5, 2.3, 5.5, 6.7, 7]
y = [5, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3]
s = interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=0)

xs = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 500)  # values for x axis
ys = s(xs)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xs, ys, label='spline')

for y0 in range(0, 7):
    r = find_roots(xs, ys - y0)
    if len(r) > 0:
        plt.scatter(r, np.repeat(y0, len(r)), label=f'y0 = {y0}')
        for ri in r:
            plt.text(ri, y0, f'  {ri:.3f}', ha='left', va='center')
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(min(x) - 0.2, max(x) + 1)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: with much less points for the x's, e.g. `xs = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 50)`, the curve would look a bit bumpy, and the interpolation would be slightly different:

[image: less points]

Comment: This looks like a linear interpolation of a sufficiently finely sampled grid.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea comparing two floats with `equal`. Use:

```
# play with `thresh`
thresh = 1e-4

root_index = np.where(np.abs(ys - ys.round())<1e-4)

printt(xs[root_index])
print(ys[root_index])
```

Output:

```
array([0.1       , 0.44779478, 2.29993999, 4.83732373, 7.        ])
array([5.        , 4.00009501, 4.99994831, 3.00006626, 3.        ])
```

Numpy also has `np.isclose`. So something like:

```
root_index = np.isclose(ys, ys.round(), rtol=1e-5, atol=1e-4)
ys[root_index]
```

And you have the same output.

Comment: Hong, thank you for your solution, but why does this not retrieve the x-values for when the y-values are 2 and for all of the times y = 4 or 5?

Comment: For the `x` values, use `xs[root_index]`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The object returned by [`scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html) is a wrapper about fitpack interpolation routines. You can get an identical interpolation using the [`CubicSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html) class: replace `s = interpolation.UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=0)` with `s = interpolation.CubicSpline(x, y)`. The results are identical, as you can see in the figure at the end.

The advantage to using `CubicSpline` is that it returns a [`PPoly`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PPoly.html) object which has working [`roots`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.roots.html) and [`solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PPoly.solve.html) methods. You can use this to compute the roots with integer offsets.

To compute the range of possible integers, you can use the [`derivative`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.derivative.html) method coupled with `roots`:

```
x_extrema = np.concatenate((x[:1], s.derivative().roots(), x[-1:]))
y_extrema = s(x_extrema)
i_min = np.ceil(y_extrema.min())
i_max = np.floor(y_extrema.max())
```

Now you can compute the roots of the offset spline:

```
x_ints = [s.solve(i) for i in np.arange(i_min, i_max + 1)]
x_ints = np.concatenate(x_ints)
x_ints.sort()
```

Here are some additional plotting commands and their output:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(xs, interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=0)(xs), label='Original Spline')
plt.plot(xs, ys, 'r:', label='CubicSpline')
plt.plot(x, y, 'x', label = 'Collected Data')

plt.plot(x_extrema, y_extrema, 's', label='Extrema')
plt.hlines([i_min, i_max], xs[0], xs[-1], label='Integer Limits')
plt.plot(x_ints, s(x_ints), '^', label='Integer Y')

plt.legend()
```

[image]

You can verify the numbers:

```
>>> s(x_ints)
array([5., 4., 4., 5., 5., 4., 3., 2., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
```